# Error generating a Backup with Tableau Server

Tags: java, tableau-api, ubuntu-18.04

Guys, I'm trying to generate a data backup of a tableau server on ubuntu 18.04 running this command

```
tsm maintenance backup -f backupTableau
```

but I'm getting this error:

Job id is '83', timeout is 1440 minutes.                                                                                                                                                             6% - Starting the Active Repository instance, File Store, and Cluster Controller.                                                                                                                    13% - Waiting for the Active Repository, File Store, and Cluster Controller to start.                                                                                                                20% - Stopping the Active Repository if necessary.                                                                                                                                                   26% - Waiting for the Active Repository to stop if necessary.                                                                                                                                        33% - Uninstalling backup services.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       An error occurred on the server generating the backup.                                                                                                                                               This job failed due to an error.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          See '/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/logs/tabadmincontroller/tabadmincontroller_*.log' on Tableau Server nodes running the Administration Controller process for server log information.

and this is the info on logs

2020-09-16 10:37:59.220 -0400  pool-15-thread-1 : ERROR com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.asyncjobs.AsyncJobService - Error running job 83 of type GenerateBackupJob                               java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                                       at com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.asyncjobs.AsyncJobService.runJob(AsyncJobService.java:228) ~[tabadmincontroller.jar:?]                                                                        at com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.asyncjobs.AsyncJobService.performJobLoop(AsyncJobService.java:124) ~[tabadmincontroller.jar:?]                                                                at com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.asyncjobs.AsyncJobService.lambda$start$1(AsyncJobService.java:106) ~[tabadmincontroller.jar:?]                                                                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)                                                   at com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.backup.FilestoreHost.isFileStoreWritable(FilestoreHost.java:141) ~[tabadmincontroller.jar:?]                                                                  at com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.asyncjobs.GenerateBackupJob.lambda$getPreferredFilestoreHost$8(GenerateBackupJob.java:353) ~[tabadmincontroller.jar:?]                                        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174) ~[?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                      at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                      at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812) ~[?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126) ~[?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                               at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486) ~[?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                          at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_232-b02]                                                                                                   at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152) ~[?:1.8.0_232-b02]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user is not able to connect to one of the processes. If your Tableau Instance is healthy,

Try:

`sudo su -`

Then

```
tsm maintenance backup -f backupTableau
```

This way you'll run it as root and make sure you there's no weird permissions problems going on.